# Microphone problem in Debian

Tags: debian, audio, firmware, microphone

I'm using Debian 11. My mic is not broken but when i using mic, it sound this thing:
https://recorder.google.com/a08ab4e2-91b7-4a02-8bd9-02d29481ef0d

I'm using ASUS UX305C with intel m3, 8gb  Ram

I have installed enough drivers but still not working.  Anyone have any solution?

Comment: Which type of mic and how is it connected to the computer? Check the computer ground connection and that of the mic, if it is powered externally. By the way, that is just noise, is that all you get? Since you provided an example, it would be better if it also had something that is not noise (voice, music, ...).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I'm using internal mic with no noise in the quiet room. I testing the mic by try say something but thats all noise I can get.